# Error whilst changing the colour of buttons "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('button'+x+'').style')"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the colour of multiple buttons in my html website, however I am running into errors when it is run.

HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:rgb(216, 216, 216);">
             
            <button id=button0 type="button" class="block" onclick="likeAction();">LIKE</button>
            
            <button id=button1 type="button" class="block" onclick="likeAction();">LIKE</button>
            
            <button id=button2 type="button" class="block" onclick="likeAction();">LIKE</button>
             
            <button id=button3 type="button" class="block" onclick="likeAction();">LIKE</button>
            
            <button id=button4 type="button" class="block" onclick="likeAction();">LIKE</button>
            
            <button id=button5 type="button" class="block" onclick="likeAction();">LIKE</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
async function likeAction(){
                for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
                    document.getElementById('button'+x+'').style.backgroundColor = 'salmon';
                }
            }
```

ERROR:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('button'+x+'').style')
```

Comment: Your `id` is not wrapped properly. It should be `id="button0"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
id=button0
```

->

```
id="button0"
```

and change

```
document.getElementById('button'+x+'')
```

->

```
document.getElementById('button'+x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some code, as shown below.

---

First, you need to change your `id` attribute in your HTML to be like this, so that it isn't invalid.

```html
<button id="<id>"></button>
```

Basically, surround the ID text with quotes.

---

Also, in your JavaScript, change your `getElementById` function to this.

```js
document.getElementById("button" + x);
```

This is because the extra empty string is redundant.

---

In summary, you were getting the error as the HTML didn't understand the ID, as you hadn't typed it in properly.